# Magento - Place Order goes to Cart Page but Order Shows

Tags: php, magento

I am running Magento 1.8.1.0 on my own VPS with 1and1. Everything was working great but now all of a sudden the checkout no longer works. Instead when you click "Place Order" it goes back to the cart page, the order is actually placed and shows up in the backend. No emails are sent or anything, and products stay in the cart still.

Link --> http://darleywebdesign.com/Bob/

My PHP Memory Limit is set to 512mb so thats not the issue. 
I know all extensions are installed.

In my developers console I get a 500 Internal Server error when clicking the button. 
Says something along the lines of

```
 POST http://darleywebdesign.com/Bob/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/form_key/rGi2D7WpduyizMIM/   500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated. Not sure what other info you would need from me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the var/log reports ?

You probably have a php error while saving the order.